# Functional tests with sqlite in memory

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony1, doctrine, phpunit

I know that already exists some topics about this, but I couldn't get any concrete answer.

I already have in memory database in Units Test with:

```
Doctrine_Core::createTablesFromModels(sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir').'/model');
Doctrine_Core::loadData(sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/phpunit/fixtures');
```

But this doesn't work with functional tests.
Always says: `no such table: user.`

But if run the test with this StepUp:

```
    Doctrine_Core::createTablesFromModels(sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir').'/model');
    Doctrine_Core::loadData(sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/phpunit/fixtures');
    Doctrine_Core::loadData(sfConfig::get('sf_test_dir').'/phpunit/fixtures');
```

Will give an exception: "Doctrine_Connection_Sqlite_Exception: Integrity constraint violation: 19 column username is not unique", which makes sense, because the username must be unique and is a proof that is loading the data into the sqlite database in memory.

I suspect that when the browser make a request, it will create a new connection for SQLite database in memory instead of using the current open by CLI.

Comment: What browser are you talking about? If it's a unit test there is no browser. You should simulate an HTTP request inside your unit test.

Comment: @yegor256 It's a functional test with selenium and firefox.
In my Unit tests, this works very well.